# What were the uses of the now obsolete/rare second person affirmative imperative of "haber" (hé)?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, imperativo, arcaísmos

#### My question in English:

> What were the uses of the now obsolete/rare second person affirmative imperative of "haber" (hé)?

I recently came upon the word **"hé"** in a book (an older edition of [***Barron's 501 Spanish Verbs***](https://books.google.com/books?id=o45FDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=barron%27s+501+spanish+verbs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7yPu-0e_ZAhVYyYMKHS0XA_UQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=barron's%20501%20spanish%20verbs&f=false)) and got to wondering how that is translated into English.  I was also curious about when it became obsolete when I decided to run it through Google's Ngram.  As you can see from the image below,

[image]

usage hasn't completely died out, so though I have yet to encounter it, I suppose I might at some point.  I took a look at some of the links to the Google book hits and ran them through a Chrome translation, but it appears that the Chrome translator doesn't know how to translate it into English either.  [**Wiktionary**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A9#Spanish) has an entry for "hé," but no translation of it.  I've also checked [**WordReference**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=h%C3%A9), [**Tureng**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/h%C3%A9), and [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/french-english/h%C3%A9), but none of them appear to be translating "hé" (at least not in the archaic sense of the word).  The dictionary of the Real Academia Española (RAE) only gives me this:

> **"La palabra hé no está registrada en el Diccionario."**

If anyone knows the answer to this, can you also add some contextual examples?
If you happen to know when the RAE eliminated it and why, even better.

---

#### Mi pregunta en español:

> Necesito saber cual es la traducción inglesa de la palabra en desuso, afirmativo imperativo para segunda persona de "haber" (hé) por lo que me pregunto ¿cómo se usó esta palabra en el español antiguo? ¿Cuándo se volvió obsoleta?

Recientemente me encontré con la palabra “hé” en un libro (una edición más vieja de [***Barron's 501 Spanish Verbs***](https://books.google.com/books?id=o45FDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=barron%27s+501+spanish+verbs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi7yPu-0e_ZAhVYyYMKHS0XA_UQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=barron's%20501%20spanish%20verbs&f=false)) y me puse a pensar cómo se traduce al inglés.  También tenía curiosidad en relación a cuando se hizo obsoleta entonces decidí pasarla por el Ngram de Google.  Como pueden ver en la imagen debajo:

[Véanse arriba.]

Su uso no está completamente extinguido.  Entonces, aunque todavía tengo que encontrarla, supongo que lo haré en algún momento.  Eché un vistazo a algunos de los enlaces de los resultados de la búsqueda de los Libros de Google e incluso los pasé por el traductor de Chrome, pero parece que ese traductor no sabe cómo traducir esta palabra tampoco.  [**Wiktionary**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A9#Spanish) tiene una entrada para “hé”, pero no traducción.  También he averiguado [**WordReference**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=h%C3%A9), [**Tureng**](https://termbank.com/en/spanish-english/h%C3%A9), y [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/french-english/h%C3%A9), pero ningunos parecen ser traduciendo “hé” (al menos no en un sentido arcaico de la palabra).  El diccionario de la Real Academia Española (RAE) sólo da esto:

> **"La palabra hé no está registrada en el Diccionario."**

Si alguien saben la respuesta a ésta, ¿puedes también añadir algunos ejemplos contextuales del uso de **hé*? Además si saben cuando la RAE la eliminó y por qué, aún mejor.

Comment: In the imperative, *haber* is regular: its forms are just *habe* and *habed* (and theoretically *habé*, but I've never seen it). *Hé* is old orthography for *he* (many single syllable words used to get accents).

Comment: (and note that *he* can be either the verb *haber* or the adverb or interjection *he* that have a different origin and don't make sense with its verbal meaning)

Comment: Lisa, note that we cannot make translations to English, that's more in the scope of the [English.SE] site. We can explain what _hé_ meant in Old Spanish, but ultimately the translation depends on you.

Comment: @guifa I appreciate your comment, but I'm a bit confused now.  It sounds as if you're saying that "hé" is just the old way of spelling "he," which is first person singular present indicative of “haber,” but also sometimes listed as second person singular imperative.

Comment: @guifa Barron's lists "hé, no hayas" for second person singular imperative. WordReference lists "habe, he" for second person singular imperative. Verbix lists "he, hé." Reverso lists just "he" for second person singular imperative. The thing is, I have yet to find an imperative use of it, let alone a translation. I know that the infinitive of "haber" is "to have," but as an auxiliary to form compound tenses. Because of that, I can't envision it being used as a command, but how is this used imperatively?

Comment: @guifa Okay.  I’ve glanced at Charlie’s examples, and have a better feel for how imperative forms of “haber” were used in the past.  I appreciate his answer and see that he must have put some time and effort into it, but sense that a student of Spanish who has come to understand this aspect of Spanish, rather than a native speaker, might be better able to explain this to someone who is at a B1 level, B2 at best.

Comment: @Charlie  I"m not following you with your comment about not being able to "make translations to English."  Do you really think this question would be accepted on the English Language & Usage StackExchange?  You went ahead and answered the question, so I'm guessing you've reconsidered.  If I were an English Language & Usage StackExchange member (and I am) and I were to see this question there, I would be perplexed as to why someone would post such a question there.  The vote up on the comment further perplexes me. Regardless, I've glanced at your answer and it looks really good. TY.

Comment: We are supposed to be Spanish experts, not English experts. If you ask for a translation from Spanish into English we may make mistakes. That's why it's against the rules of this site. But we can surely explain the Spanish concept you want to know about as best as we can, so that you can get your own conclusions and ultimately make the translation yourself. That's what I tried to do. Note that I do not attempt to translate the term as you asked in the first place, but I really hope you can after my response.

Comment: Maybe so, @Charlie, but did you know that "traducción" is a tag and that there are 1,332 questions tagged with it?  (This is 25% of the total number of questions asked here at the Spanish StackExchange.)  And if asking about the translation is against the rules, that's news to me.  I've read the [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page and if users are being advised to refrain from asking about how something is translated into English is on there somewhere, I don't see it.

Comment: In fact, I hope that never becomes policy because this is one of the best sites to come to when you can't find the meaning for something any place else.

Comment: Yes, Lisa, I'm aware of that. The translation tag is one of the most popular ones, and it's used like this: "In my language I can say X, how can I say it in Spanish?". The opposite tag is "significado": "I bumped into this word/expression in Spanish, what's its meaning?". Maybe we could do translations into English, but think about other languages. If we let people ask for translations into English, we should also let people ask for translations into Japanese. That's why those questions should be asked in other sites.

Comment: @Charlie But does it really make sense to you that those on the English Language & Usage StackExchange would have the faintest clue about how to translate something from Spanish into English? The number who are bilingual — Spanish-English/English-Spanish bilingual — is likely to be minuscule at best. My chances of having such a question reasonably answered is far greater here on the Spanish StackExchange.  Also, I've read the tag descriptions for both "traducción" and "significado.” ….

Comment: @Charlie … Maybe those two words are "opposites" to you, but they aren't to me. In fact, I wasn't aware that the word "traducción" had an opposite. It doesn't in English. If you disagree, please tell me what it is because I find no antonym for the word [here](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/translation). Now, if the tag designer meant to have us use "traducción" for translations of English into Spanish and "significado" for translations of Spanish into English, that needs to be made much more abundantly clear than it is now. TY4 pointing it out to me, though.

Comment: As a non-native speaker of Spanish, I've never thought to use the "significado" tag, because any question about meaning is likely to be to or from the Spanish language and therefore a question of translation, not meaning (though meaning would be an aspect of translation, I suppose). If I were fluent in Spanish (as I am in English), then "significado" would make more sense for me to use. Do you see my point here? I'm not trying to be argumentative or rude to you, @Charlie. I just don't get a warm and fuzzy that you understand my mindset on this, and I'm just trying to paint a clearer picture.

Comment: Think about other languages, such as Swahili. What would you do to translate a word from Spanish to Swahili? Certainly there are very few people that know both languages, so first you make sure that you understand what the term in Spanish means, and that you can express in Swahili the concept behind the word, and then you ask what word do we have in Swahili that express the same concept? English is no exception. First we provide you with a concept you can explain in your language, and then you can go to ELU and ask for a word that matches the concept you learnt.

Comment: @Charlie That last comment was a bit out in left field for me, so let me just quote from your answer. In your answer, you quote Tomás Carrasquilla with, "Pero hé aquí que la Luna,  ..." And then you write, "La mayoría de casos de hé del siglo XX tienen la forma "hé aquí" o "hé ahí ..." To make this simple, let's disregard the conjecture that follows and just focus on this alone. That bit right there, after I translate it in my head into something that makes sense to me in English is precisely the answer I was looking for and what got you the green checkmark ...

Comment: @Charlie ... but I think I know what you've been trying to tell me now ... that there's been some debate or uncertainty about what expressions with the word "hé" mean in Spanish, let alone a translation into another language, whether it be English or any other.  Nevertheless, this would never be a question that the members of the English Language & Usage StackExchange would accept as viable fodder for answer and/or discussion in its forums.  If you disagree and can find a native English speaker who would find this question acceptable there, I'd love to hear their thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

Como comenta @guifa, la forma *hé* no es más que la forma *he* pero con tilde. Su uso con tilde puede venir influenciada por aquellos monosílabos que sí la tienen, pero por motivos concretos. Por regla general, los monosílabos no tienen tilde salvo que puedan servir para dos cosas distintas (ejemplo: *de* y *dé*). Aprenderse cuáles son los monosílabos con tilde puede ser complicado, y así hoy día podemos ver muchos casos de personas que escriben *pié* con tilde cuando no debería llevarla, por citar un ejemplo.

Revisando la primera gramática de 1771 vemos que por entonces ya se especificaba que el verbo *haber* en dicha conjugación (primera persona singular de indicativo) iba sin tilde. Su uso como imperativo es, actualmente y [según la RAE](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QnOAsszgaRqBfChf), un arcaismo que se ha "fosilizado en la fórmula presentativa *he aquí*, *henos ahora* o *hete aquí*".

Así pues, vámonos al CORDE y veamos ejemplos de frases con *hé*, a ver si podemos encontrar alguna cuyo significado sea diferente al esperado. Lo curioso es que se pueden encontrar casos, como afirmas, hasta en el siglo XX:

> *Pero hé aquí que la Luna, al bañar el Río con sus destellos, divulga en la superficie todo el oro.*
>
> Tomás Carrasquilla, "Hace tiempos", 1935-1936 (Colombia).

Su uso debería ser *he aquí* (la fórmula arcaica que sí usa *he* como imperativo). La mayoría de casos de *hé* del siglo XX tienen la forma "hé aquí" o "hé ahí", lo cual se puede justificar pensando que la gente podría considerar que no es un uso habitual de "he" y por tanto lo marca con tilde, mas no es así. Los ejemplos que se encuentran en el siglo XIX (mucho más numerosos) son prácticamente todos de "hé aquí" o "hé ahí", expresión que como se ve se usaba más por entonces, y es lo que hace que en NGram aparezca un repunte de "hé" hacia 1860.

Sigamos hacia atrás:

> *En tres ócaciones hé remitido señor dos recivos uno de quatro tercios de sal, y un cajon de cuchillos á favor de ésta Mision [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Otra carta del cura de San Martín dirigida al gobernador [Documentos lingüísticos de Bolivia]", 1769 (Bolivia).

En el siglo XVIII se encuentran pocos casos, y son casi todos en su forma "hé" + participio. Es decir, que igualmente se deberían haber escrito como "he".

En el siglo XVII la cosa es un poco más diversa. Hay casos de "hé aquí", "hé" + participio, y algunos curiosos como este:

> *El de las siete rosas, qué se à hecho? corrió, ó padeció aduersa fortuna? hé, hé, hé, cogieronle en la red, y con esso está concluso su pleito.*
>
> Fray Jacinto de la Serna, "Tratado de las supersticiones, idolatrías, hechicerías, ritos y otras costumbres gentílicas de las razas aborígenes de México", 1656 (México).

Juraría que en este caso se trata de la onomatopeya de la risa, que hoy escribimos como "je je". Otros casos son tal que así:

> *Las abusiones y agüeros destos indios eran tantos, que no fácilmente se puede hacer memoria de todos; contentarme hé con referir en este capítulo los más ordinarios y generales.*
>
> Bernabé Cobo, "Historia del Nuevo Mundo", 1653 (España).

En este caso, "contentarme hé" equivale a "he de contentarme". Tal vez al escribir así la construcción, que en otros textos se puede encontrar contraída (tal que así: "contentarm'hé"), la pronunciación de seguido hace pensar que la palabra va toda junta, y al ser aguda llevaría tilde. Pero sigue siendo "he" tal y como lo conocemos hoy.

Hacia el siglo XVI no hay novedad, los casos siguen siendo como los ya comentados, aunque empiezan a aparecer casos en los que equivale a "tengo":

> *... yo setenta años tengo, no hé memoria haverme contradicho voto que una vez diese á mi mismo...*
>
> Anónimo, "Cortes de Toledo 1538", 1538-1539 (España).

Ya más hacia atrás abunda más este último uso, aunque se siguen encontrando casos de los anteriores mencionados.

Finalizando ya, habiendo expuesto los usos de *hé* a lo largo de la historia, queda en tus manos sacar conclusiones acerca de cuál sería la traducción correcta al inglés de la palabra, imagino que ya acorde a cuál es el sentido de la frase en la que se emplee.

Comment: *He* no es imperativo, sino adverbio y viene de la palabra árabe *ha* como indica el DLE. Es curioso que la Gramática lo considere forma de *haber*

Comment: @guifa la gramática y el diccionario. Si buscas "haber" y le das a conjugar, efectivamente viene "he" como imperativo de la segunda persona de singular, junto a "habe". Y en la gramática si ves el enlace se dice lo de la forma fosilizada del imperativo arcaico que comento en la respuesta. Pero claro, ahora me dices (y efectivamente [es así](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K3tgQNM|K3u28aq)) que es un adverbio. ¿En qué quedamos? ¿Se está contradiciendo la RAE a sí misma? ¿O es que entre los académicos no se ponen de acuerdo?

Comment: To save this answer I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: La RAE se equivoca. Es imposible que *he* sea adverbio si se le pueden añadir pronombres enclíticos (*henos*, etc.). Eso solo se puede con verbos.

Comment: @CarlosArturoSerrano y porque no? Incluso si lo analizamos como verbo, es una construcción increíblemente especial e irregular. Pero hay constancia de que estos clíticos en otros idiomas ibéricos pueden aparecer con palabras que no sean verbos. Acaso nunca oíste la construcción **Ú + [pron.dir.]**: *Dá-ylu a María por favor. / Val, ensin problema pero, **¿úla?*** Ú es adverbio que significa *dónde*.

Comment: El portugués también tiene el adverbio **eis** que funciona de una forma muy parecida a *he* en castellano: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/eis/14873

Comment: Para mí el hecho de que es invariable en cuanto a número y trato significa que no podemos considerarlo verbo. Si es de verdad un imperativo, sería forma tuteante (no hay mandato formal monosílabo). Pero lo empleamos más que nada en contextos formales sin emplear algo como *haya aquí algo* ni lo variamos para contextos formales como *hen/hayan aquí algo*. Y rarísimo queda si le anteponemos un cordial *por favor, heme algo aquí* (cosa que aceptaría cualquier mandato)

Comment: Ah y también *contentarme he* equivale más directamente a *me contentaré* (*haber de* puede implicar futuro, pero la estructura mesoclítica ha de implicarlo ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

When you ask [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jv4Frsm) to conjugate the verb **haber**, it does list **he** as a second person singular imperative, *besides* being the first person singular indicative. So it seems to not be officially obsolete, although nobody ever actually uses it.

Since imperatives in English are the same words as the base verb, the corresponding English translation of the imperative would be simply **have**.

Comment: The imperative form _he_ of the verb _haber_ in Spanish is only used in expressions such as _he aquí_, _hete ahí_, _henos aquí_ and so on. In such expressions the translations to English won't be using _to have_ necessarily. Example: _henos aquí_ would be _here we are_. And _he aquí_ is used to catch the attention of the reader, much like the English _behold_.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and your inclusion of an authoritative source such as the RAE, but I was referring to "hé" -- "he" with an accented "e" and not just "he."