# ¿Se corresponde un "hé, hé, hé" de 1656 con la onomatopeya de la risa? ¿Cómo ha evolucionado esta con el tiempo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, historia, acentuación, onomatopeyas

Buscando información para [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24500/12637), di con el siguiente texto del siglo XVII:

> *El de las siete rosas, qué se à hecho? corrió, ó padeció aduersa fortuna? hé, hé, hé, cogieronle en la red, y con esso está concluso su pleito.*
>
> Fray Jacinto de la Serna, "Tratado de las supersticiones, idolatrías, hechicerías, ritos y otras costumbres gentílicas de las razas aborígenes de México", 1656 (México).

En la respuesta que di cité este mismo texto y di por supuesto que era la onomatopeya de la risa tal y como se escribía en la época (y puede que el lugar). Sin embargo, no estoy del todo seguro, así que os pregunto:

¿Se correponde el uso de *hé* en el texto con la onomatopeya de la risa? Si es así, ¿cómo ha evolucionado esta onomatopeya con el tiempo? ¿Se escribía *he*, *hé* o de alguna otra forma? Si no es así, ¿a qué corresponde el uso de *hé* en el texto citado?

Comment: Yo de esto no se mucho, pero creo que la h no sonaba j antes. Ahora con la influencia del inglés rápidamente nos vamos al sonido j. Si lo leo en voz alta pero solo con el sonido é, é, é y haciendo relación a hechicería y ritos, suena como a _espantando brujas_ y no a risas :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. *«hé, hé, hé»* como risa

Sí aún en esa época así era una forma de escribir las risas. Mira aquí:

> SEM. He, he, he.
>
> ELI. De que te ries? de mal cancer ſea comida eſſa boca deſgraciada y enojoſa.
>
> - [*Celestina. Tragicomedia de Calisto y Melibea*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=44R47u15SWQC&pg=PA172&dq="h%C3%A9,+h%C3%A9,+h%C3%A9"), Fernando de Rojas (1599)

Además, en las obras de Lope de Vega (por ejemplo) encontramos 'he', 'ha' y 'ay' como risas:

> *Todos.* ha,ha,ha,he,he,he, que todo lo negro me vengan ave, de tuuociontu de ſanto Thome.
>
> - [*Las comedias del famoso poeta Lope de Vega Carpio*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=E7Ye4Uc4gFcC&pg=PP726&dq="h%C3%A9,+h%C3%A9,+h%C3%A9")
>     *De los negros de Santo Thome* (1609)

> El hozico de voſameſe,
>   he,he,he
>   me tiene periro, de amore venciro,
>   ay,ay,he,ay,ay,he
>   que me morire, que me morire.
>   El hozico neglo,
>   he,he,he,
>   y lo diente dentro, ay,ay,he,
>
> blanco ſobre prieto,he,he,he,
>   neglo tiene muerto,he,he,he,
>   si non dà remedio,triſte yo que harè.
>   El hozico dc vofa meſe,he,he,he,
>   me tiene pcríro,dc amore venciro,
>   ay,ay,he,que me morire,ay,ay,he,
>   hozíco mi dama,hc,.he,hc,
>   anima me ſaca,ay,ay,he,
>   aino ſamo ingrata,he,he,he,
>   con eya me [caſa],ay,ay,he,
>   no queremo branca,aunque quere â me.
>   El hozico de voſa meſe,he,he,he,
>   me tiene periro,de amore venciro,
>   ay,ay,he,que me morire,que me morire.
>
> - [*Decima octava Parte de las Comedias de L. de V. C*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fltoAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA253-IA1&dq="h%C3%A9,+h%C3%A9,+h%C3%A9")
>     *El Capellan de la Virgen* (1623)

---

## 2. La evolución de la risa escrita

Con los cambios de sonidos en la lengua española:

`j: [ʃ] → [x]`  (cc siglo XIX)
`h: [h] →  ∅`   (cc siglo XVII)

La forma de expresar una risa también había cambiado, y se puede encontrar muchísimos ejemplos de *'ja, ja, ja'* etc desde el siglo XIX:

[image]

---

**Notas:**

> <sup>Until the 15th century both [f-] and [h-] were written as f. However, with the emergence of the phonemic distinction just alluded to, Spanish orthography began to reserve f for the first sound and h for the second. On the other hand, by the 16th century, /h/ was on the way to being eliminated from the phonemic inventory of Castilian Spanish, although the letter h was retained in the spelling system (and remains there, a curious anomaly in an otherwise largely phonemic system).</sup>
>
> - https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/cons.htm

Answer (score 1):

La letra H en un pasado remoto tenía un sonido cercano a la F que con el tiempo fue desaparenciendo:

Les remito lo siguiente tomado de [La incógnita de la letra H: ¿por qué existe si no suena?](http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-41667461)

> El caso es que la **H** no siempre fue muda. Los fenicios, los primeros al parecer en utilizarla, la pronunciaban como una "J" aspirada. Los griegos la adoptaron del fenicio dándole la forma mayúscula con que hoy la conocemos y pronunciándola como una suave aspiración. Del griego paso al latín, donde poco a poco fue suavizando su sonido.
>
> Del latín la **H** dio el salto al español, donde también en un principio se decía aspirada, es decir, acompañada de una pequeña explosión de aire similar a la que caracteriza hoy en día a la pronunciación de la H aspirada del inglés.
>
> Pero, además de adueñarse de varios vocablos en latín que iniciaban con la H, el español se apropió también de numerosas palabras latinas que empezaban con **F**, y que también en castellano comenzaban en un principio con esa letra.
>
> Pero con el pasar de los años, y dado que en algunas zonas de España esa F se pronunciaba también aspirada, esa letra inicial empezó a ser sustituida por la H a partir del siglo XIV.
>
> Es el caso por ejemplo de farina, que pasó a ser harina; del verbo hacer (que en sus orígenes era facer), de helecho (felecho en la Edad Media), herir (ferir), hurto (furto), humo (fumo), higo (en "El Cantar del Mío Cid", que data de alrededor del año 1200, aparece como figo) y tantos otros vocablos. Y ese cambio también afectó a palabras que tenían la H intercalada, como es el caso de búho (bufo en latín).
>
> La RAE sostiene que hasta mediados del siglo XVI la H aún se pronunciaba por medio de una aspiración en algunas palabras, sobre todo en aquellas que originalmente comenzaban por la F latina. Al principio, era la gente culta la que al hablar pronunciaba la H mediante una ligera aspiración.
> Pero a partir del siglo XV, esa tendencia cambió y las haches aspiradas comenzaron a considerarse un vulgarismo, algo propio de las clases bajas y de gente no instruida. Y así, sigilosa y paulatinamente, la H enmudeció completamente.

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, no creo que la palabra sea una onomatopeya de la risa.  Ni creo que sea una forma del verbo haber.

1. No creo que el concepto de la risa encaje bien con el sentido total de la cita, y aun si fuera una posibilidad, no se escribiría con una 'h', ya que la letra 'h' es silenciosa.
2. Otra conjugación de la palabra haber aparece en la primera pregunta en la cita sin una h inicial "qué se **à** hecho"

En el Diccionario Etimológico De Español En Línea (http://etimologias.dechile.net/) se explica que la palabra "he" es un adverbio que se usa para señalar (como, por ejemplo, en la expresión "he aquí")--y sabemos que no proviene del Latín ("habere"), porque en El Cantar del Mio Cid, aparece con una 'f' inicial ("fe aquí").

A mi parecer, en esta cita, el significado más apto sería "¡Ahí está!" o "¡Lo pillaron!" (...cogieronle en la red...)

Comment: Resulta interesante esta opción. Podría interpretarse como "lo cogieron en la red, ¿eh?, ¿eh?", como diciendo "¿ves?, ¿ves?". Sin embargo, se ha comentado que hace algunos siglos la "h" no era muda y que por tanto la onomatopeya de la risa se escribía "he", y han dado algunos ejemplos. A mí personalmente no me parece que una risa esté fuera de lugar en el caso del texto de la pregunta, aunque el hecho de que esté escrito "hé" (con tilde) me desconcierta. ¿Tienes otros ejemplos de textos similares que dejen claro que "hé" significa lo que propones?